# json format to list of floats

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, floating-point

How can I change the type of my string list to `float` in Python?

This is my data:

```
{"time":20180124,"data1m":"[[1516752000,11590.6,11616.9,11590.4,11616.9,0.25202387],[1516752060,11622.4,11651.7,11622.4,11644.6,1.03977764]]"}
```

This list is assigning every element an index like:

```
a[0] = [, a[1] = [ and a[2] = 1,
```

I want `[1516752000,11590.6,11616.9,11590.4,11616.9,0.25202387]` to be stored in one index and then `a[0][0] = 1516752000` and so on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `json` module to convert the string value of `data1m` into a list-of-lists, and then convert the elements of sub-lists into `float`s like this:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

data = {"time":20180124,
        "data1m":"[[1516752000,11590.6,11616.9,11590.4,11616.9,0.25202387],"
                  "[1516752060,11622.4,11651.7,11622.4,11644.6,1.03977764]]"}

a = json.loads(data["data1m"])
for index, row in enumerate(a):
    a[index] = list(map(float, row))

pprint(a)
```

Output:

```
[[1516752000.0, 11590.6, 11616.9, 11590.4, 11616.9, 0.25202387],
 [1516752060.0, 11622.4, 11651.7, 11622.4, 11644.6, 1.03977764]]
```

Comment: That answer looks shockingly familar.

Comment: What is `map(float, row)` providing?  `json.loads` returns floats if appropriate?

Comment: @martineau
Thankyou so much sir, it works for me.
Best Regards

Comment: @Stephen: Close, but not exactly the same. I did the `map()` because the OP said they wanted `float`s, which I took to literally mean _all_ the values in the rows.

Comment: @Stephen: To be more precise, the first value in each of the rows of the sample input aren't floats, they're integers.

Answer (score 3):

This data can be parsed with the `json` module like:

#### Code:

```
a = json.loads(data['data1m'])
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = {
    "time": 20180124,
    "data1m": "[[1516752000,11590.6,11616.9,11590.4,11616.9,0.25202387],"
              "[1516752060,11622.4,11651.7,11622.4,11644.6,1.03977764]]"
}
import json
a = json.loads(data['data1m'])
print(a)
```

#### Results:

```
[
    [1516752000, 11590.6, 11616.9, 11590.4, 11616.9, 0.25202387],
    [1516752060, 11622.4, 11651.7, 11622.4, 11644.6, 1.03977764]
]
```

Comment: Thanks for ur interest @Stephen
but im having a big data inside 'data1m' and im opening a json file in my python code, so i cant insert a " in my data, is this possible without using " or can i add " to my file

Comment: @HadiRajani, I have no idea what you just asked me.  Can you clarify.

Comment: import json

with open('testing.json') as f:
 data = json.load(f)

im using this code to open a json file, and that file contains data
 {
 "time": 20180124,
 "data1m": "[[1516752000,11590.6,11616.9,11590.4,11616.9,0.25202387],[1516752060,11622.4,11651.7,11622.4,11644.6,1.03977764],[1516752120,11642,11642,11600.2,11623.6,0.86759505],...]
and all these elements are considered as an index, i just want [1516752000,11590.6,11616.9,11590.4,11616.9,0.25202387] to be a single index and so on for the other indexes, is this possible
kind regards

Comment: @HadiRajani, this is much worse.  Totally undecipherable.  Suggest you edit your question.

Comment: simple is that, I can not add inverted commas after closing square bracket i.e ']' what can i do

Comment: What is an inverted comma?

Comment: " this inverted comma

Comment: That looks like a quote to me.

Comment: and when i ad this, a = json.loads(set['data1m'])
it shows me 
"TypeError: string indices must be integers" this error